# Regex for Comma delimited list of domain

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for the Regex to validate the list of domains which have comma as separator. For example:

```
yahoo.com, google.com, facebook.net
```

The code for single domain is:

^\S*\b((?=[a-z0-9-]{1,63}.)(xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*.)+[a-z]{2,63}\S*$\b/

Appreciate your help

Comment: Can you share your current code?

Comment: I feel like your easiest bet is to split the string on “, “ and then loop through the new array of single domains and validate each one with your regex.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to split them and use [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

> The `every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.

in the following way:

```js
var validDomains = 'yahoo.com, google.com, facebook.net';
var invalidDomains = 'yahoo.c, google.com, facebook.net';
function checkDomains(domains){
  return domains.split(',').every(function(d){
    var reg = /[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}/;
    return reg.test(d.trim());
  });
}

console.log(checkDomains(validDomains));
console.log(checkDomains(invalidDomains));
```